# Is it possible to access struts2 variable in jsp scriptlet?

Tags: jsp, struts2

Is it possible to access struts2 variable in jsp scriptlet?

If I have struts2 variable like

```
<s:set var="test" value="%{'true'}"/>
```

Can I use variable "test" in JSP scriptlet?

If yes. How is it possible?

Can anyone give some idea about it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<jsp:useBean id="test" class="java.lang.String" scope="request"/>

<%
         test = "false";
%>

1. outside scriptlet: <c:out value="${test}"/>   <!-- will not print anything -->

<%
    out.println("2. in scriptlet: " + test);     // will print false
%>

<c:set var="test" value="true" />

3. outside scriptlet: <c:out value="${test}"/>   <!-- will print true -->

<%
    out.println("4. in scriptlet: " + test);     // will print false
%>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can even use the request object to get the action variable. For example, if you have a variable `String userName` in the action, you can use

```
<%
String userName = (String) request.getAttribute("userName");
%>
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes,

```
<s:set var="jspVariable" value="%{strutsVariable}"/>
<jsp:useBean id="jspVariable" type="com.example.Object" />
<%=jspVariable%>
```

Comment: Why we need to add a extra bean for just getting the value of variable defined in JSP file?

Comment: This idea to assign the value from plain java to struts tag <s:set> and then later use it from the variable defined in <s:set> made things work for me