# Struts JSP/html inserting current date

Tags: java, html, jsp, struts2

My question is very simular to this one: 
[Is it possible to access struts2 variable in jsp scriptlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929036/is-it-possible-to-access-struts2-variable-in-jsp-scriptlet)

In my .jsp page I have a form in which I would like to preset a text field to the current date. My only issue is that "value" does not support runtime expressions when using Struts - which makes sense I want to keep as much Java out of the JSP as possible. But this leaves me struggling to get the variable out of an action. 
I am currently running on Tomcat v7.0 and Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Version: Kepler Service Release 2.

in my .jsp page I have:

```
   <s:set var="currentDate" value="currentDate"/>
   <s:property value="currentDate"/>

   <s:form action= "updateAction">
  <s:textfield name="dateUpdated" key="label.dateUpdated" size="20" value="%{currentDate}" />
   <s:submit method="execute" key="submit"/>
   </s:form>
```

Now I have three actions - one to get to this page(ToPageAction), one for when the form is submitted(UpdateAction), one that gets the currentDate variable(GetCurrentDateAction).

I think I am going crazy >.<

anyways, the action to get the currentDate variable is called GetCurrentDateAction and looks like:

```
 public class GetCurrentDateAction extends ActionSupport {

SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
public String currentDate = date.toString();

public String getCurrentDate(){
    return currentDate;
}
public void setVariable(String currentDate){
    this.currentDate=currentDate;
}
public String execute() throws Exception{
    return SUCCESS;

}
}
```

additionally in struts.xml I have:

```
 <action name="getCurrentDateAction"
class="net.upsmon.struts2.action.GetCurrentDateAction">
<result name="success">AlertPersistencyView.jsp</result>
</action>
```

I have read through the question I linked to many, many times and tried to format my own struts correctly but find myself getting lost. I am not sure if the answers are just misleading or I am just not understanding something I feel like this issue cannot be too difficult to solve. in my .jsp page I have a property tag to prove to myself that I got the variable into the .jsp but it has not yet worked. And additionally my textfield is blank. Any advice out there for me to get this variable into my .jsp? Is there any additional information I can provide for a solution? I unerstand the basics of Struts and any advice is welcome.

An additional piece of information: I have been also looking at [this](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-set-tag-example/) blog in order to figure out my issue,  but have still not come up with a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a JSP, which to my understanding is what you are doing based on the format of your question header, I would format it like so(depending on how you would like your date to look changes the way the date is built). You could do it like this

```
<%@page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat, java.util.Calendar, java.text.DateFormat"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     <head>
         <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
         <title>Date Tester</title>
     </head>
     <body>
         <%
             DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
             Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();           
         %>
        <form>
            <label for="date">Your Text Field: </label><br/>
            <textarea type="" name="date" value="" >Today's Date: <%=    dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()) + "\n" %></textarea>
        <!-- The rest of your form here -->
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps! if not leave a comment and I will try again.

Comment: this works beautifully - except I really would like to get it inside a s:textfield and when I do that I get:  According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute value does not accept any expressions

Comment: @user3761189 I have changed the above code to use a text field instead of an input tag for the user try it and see how you like it. Let me know

Comment: I think my issue is because I am using struts - thanks so much for your help so far. I am going to look into it in more detail and see if I can figure it out - you've been very helpful though

Comment: I have updated my question so it is more relevant to my actual problem, my question before was poorly written, sorry for any confusion

Answer (score 0):

```
 <p id="demo"></p>
 <script>
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date();
 </script>
```

Comment: can you please include some text explaining this code? otherwise it is not very helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [JSP Standard Tag Library](https://jstl.java.net/) and always try to avoid *Scriplet elements*.

Sample code:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>

<jsp:useBean id="today" class="java.util.Date" />

<textarea>
    <fmt:formatDate value="${today}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" />
</textarea>
```

Comment: This is a clever idea, but because I am using struts, value will not support a runtime expression :/

Comment: Have you tried it? what is this `<%=    dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()) + "\n" %>`. Scriplet in 21st century.

Comment: You didn't answered. Have you tried it?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, what you have posted will still not work because it is a runtime expression and the "value" tag does not accept run time expresions - I believe the solution will have to involve the Struts framework and an action class