# Access to controller methods in JSP Java scriptlet rather than using tags?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl, valuestack

My struts configuration:

```
<action name="myAction" class="my.controller.MyAction">
    <result name="myPage">/myPage.jsp</result>
```

`MyAction` has a method `public String getSomeValue() { ... }`.

In `myPage.jsp`, I can print that value easily to the HTML stream:

```
<s:property value="someValue" />
```

However, I would like to print it to the console:

```
<%

//how do I reference myActionBean
String someVal = myActionBean.getSomeValue();
System.out.println(someVal);

%>
```

My question is, how do I reference the action controller (replace `myActionBean` in the code above) inside a JSP code block, just like the `s:property` tag does in its syntax that eliminates the "get" part of the method ? I would like to access `myActionBean.getSomeValue()` in Java in the JSP rather than doing it in a tag. I know this is not a recommended way of doing things but this is just for debugging.

Comment: I know how to do a scriptlet.  The question is in the last paragraph of the post.

Comment: `how do I reference the action controller ... inside a JSP code block?`

Comment: it's just for debugging.  i need to print to the console

Comment: For debugging use debugger or logs in your controller.

Comment: **I want to print from the JSP into the console and I want to access controller methods in a scriptlet.**  You may not like what I want to do but that's what I want to do at this point.

Comment: **Actually I don't care**. :) Your question smells like XY problem. Can you explain why do you need to print to system.out from jsp?

Comment: because it's convenient in my scenario that i won't take 30 min to explain and i don't see why I shouldn't be able to access the controller methods through Java in a scriptlet.

Comment: Your call. But you already have spent ~10min to argue instead of providing exact info.

Comment: the question is simple:  **How do I access controller methods in a Java scriptlet in a JSP rather than using JSP tags?**

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: The action is available in the action stack. You *can* retrieve it, but it seems completely pointless since you can (a) dump it to the HTML itself using JSP EL, (b) get the action context via the `<s:debug>` tag, or (c) log it from within the action itself. Or https://struts.apache.org/docs/access-to-valuestack-from-jsps.html, or http://stackoverflow.com/q/929036/438992. I'll echo Aleksandr's comments--this is the least best way to debug. It's inefficient, more trouble than it's worth, and is outside of the best tools for the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @DaveNewton, I was able to access the action class from the context:

```
<%
    ActionContext context = ActionContext.getContext();

    //this will access actionClass.getFoo() just like the tag
    //<s:property value="%{foo}"/> does but outputs to HTML
    Object fooObj = context.getValueStack().findValue("foo");
    String fooStr = (String)fooObj;

    //so that we can print it to the console
    //because the tag can only output to HTML 
    //and printing to the console is the objective of the question
    System.out.println("foo = " + fooStr);
%>
```

I had to import `ActionContext` on top of the JSP:

```
<%@ page import="com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext" %>
```

I understand some folks don't like that I should want to do this but that is actually exactly what I wanted to do. I know well that I could do a `System.out` in `getFoo()` itself but I wanted to do it in the JSP.

Comment: Good you figured this out +1. Don't forget to accept your answer, it might help future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

You can get action bean from action invocation like you do in the interceptor or from the value stack where it's already pushed. Since you have access to the value stack from JSP and know how to print property the easiest way for you to set the action bean to the request attribute with `<s:set>` tag.

```jsp
<s:set var="action" value="action" scope="request"/>
```

Now you can get the action bean

```jsp
<% 
  MyAction myActionBean = request.getAttribute("action");
  String someVal = myActionBean.getSomeValue();
  System.out.println(someVal);
%>
```

Comment: did you try this solution?